# How do I add conditional fractions to geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm comparing two categorical variables in the Carseats data.

**Initialize the dataset**

```
library('ISLR')
data(Carseats)
attach(Carseats)
```

**Plot the viz**

```
Carseats %>% 
  count(ShelveLoc, Urban) %>%  
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = ShelveLoc, y = Urban)) +
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = n)) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white",aes(label=paste(round((n/sum(n)*100)),"%",sep=""))) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white", nudge_y = .1, aes(label=paste(n))) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white", nudge_y = -.1, aes(label=n))
```

That gets me this -->

[image]

I'd like the third value to show the percent by class.

The bottom right would show the result from this equation

`68 (count that is medium and no) / 118 (count that is no)`

The top right would show the result from this equation

`151 (count that is medium and yes) / 282 (count that is yes)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Carseats %>% 
  count(ShelveLoc, Urban) %>%
  group_by(Urban) %>%
  mutate(yes_no_pct = round(n / sum(n) * 100)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = ShelveLoc, y = Urban)) +
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill = n)) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white", aes(label = paste0('Percent of Total: ', round((n / sum(n) * 100)), '%'))) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white", nudge_y = .1, aes(label = paste0('Count: ', n))) + 
  geom_text(colour = "white", nudge_y = -.1, aes(label = paste0('Percent of Group: ', yes_no_pct, '%'))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the advantage to paste0?

Comment: `paste0()` == `paste(sep = "")`